# Get the ObjectMapper that is used in @RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a Spring Boot `@RestController` which hast an upload endpiont that gets an object as input.

```
 public ResponseEntity<Void> upload(String productId, Boolean dryrun, ProductConfig product)
```

This endpoint receives an xml file with a `ProductConfig` in it. I have some Jackson annotations for renaming xml elements and configuration to use unwrapped lists by default on the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and it works fine.

So my problem is now that I need this `ObjectMapper` inside one of my tests to parse one of those xml files from the resources. I tried two different things:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{

        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("SimpleConfig.xml");
        ProductConfig conf = mapper.readValue(res.getFile(), ProductConfig.class);
    }
}
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("SimpleConfig.xml");
        ProductConfig conf = mapper.readValue(res.getFile(), ProductConfig.class);
    }
}
```

The first one is the one I would have expected to work but it crashes with a parse exception on the '<'character, which seems that it wants to parse json and not xml, but in the `@RestController` it gets parsed perfectly,... or is ObjectMapper just not the class that does the parsing for the `@RestController`?

In the second example it fails to parse some nested classes namely `ProductConfig` can have a list of `Unit`s, which is an unrwapped list of `<unit>` child elements. The respective part of the model is:

```
  @JsonProperty("units")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "unit")
  @Valid
  private List<Unit> units = null;
```

This works when I just upload the xml to the rest endpoint but doesn't work when I invoke the `XmlMapper` manually.

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product name="foobar">
    <unit  target="config">
        <property name="prop1" value="foo"/>

        <unit target="sub1">
            <property name="prop1" value="foo"/>
            <property name="prop2" value="bar"/>
            <property name="prop3" value="blah"/>
        </unit>
        <unit target="sub2">
           ....
        </unit>
        ...
    </unit>
</product>
```

Any ideas on how to reproduce the parsing the `@RestController` does for tests?

Comment: Could you please share xml content, additional, did you specify any property naming strategy?

Comment: @027 I added an example of how the xml is structured. The weird thing is, when I upload the xml to the rest endpoint it works completely fine, so by extension If I were to use the same mapper, that the rest controller uses, I should get the same results. That's why I wanted to get the same mapper instance as the controller uses.